# Opencl and kernel function

Tags: opencl

I do small operation in opencl using single  parameter function as

```
__kernel void hello(__global int *x){}
```

While creating program with following code works

```
ret=clBuildProgram (program,1,&deviceid,Null,Null,Null);
```

But for code

```
__kernel void  hello(__global int *x,__global int *y){}
```

The clbulidprogram throws error. What is mistake when loading function more than one parameter.

Comment: What is the return status code, and the contents of  CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS return from clGetProgramBuildInfo?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you not have function name? Was that intentional?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience function namd is hello.